# ipython: how to set terminal width

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

When I use `ipython terminal` and want to print a `numpy.ndarray` which has many columns, the lines are automatically broken somewhere around 80 characters (i.e. the width of the lines is cca 80 chars):

```
z = zeros((2,20))
print z
```

Presumably, ipython expects that my terminal has 80 columns. In fact however, my terminal has width of 176 characters and I would like to use the full width.

I have tried changing the following parameter, but this has no effect:

```
c.PlainTextFormatter.max_width = 160
```

**How can I tell `ipython` to use full width of my terminal ?**

I am using `ipython 1.2.1` on Debian Wheezy

Comment: By the way, this isn't iPython-specific, so you may want to update your tags to reflect this. The behavior is specific to `numpy`, and is the same whether you use iPython or any other Python interpreter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand width of shell in Python's IDLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770614/expand-width-of-shell-in-pythons-idle)

Comment: The 1980s called. They want their terminal width back. :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some digging through the code, it appears that the variable you're looking for is `numpy.core.arrayprint._line_width`, which is 75 by default. Setting it to 160 worked for me:

```
>>> numpy.zeros((2, 20))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

The function used by default for array formatting is `numpy.core.numeric.array_repr`, although you can change this with `numpy.core.numeric.set_string_function`.

Comment: there is no `numpy.core.arrayprint._line_width` in my `$HOME/.config/ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`. Should I just ad the line there, or does `numpy` have it's own config file somewhere else?

Comment: @MartinVegter: I'm not speaking about config files, and I doubt `numpy` even has one. It's an ordinary Python variable, and you can set it simply by executing `numpy.core.arrayprint._line_width = 160` after having imported numpy. If you want to make it default somehow, then I'm afraid I can't help you, since I don't know how iPython does its startup sequence and what kind of rc-files it may or may not run. Depending on your setup, you may want to consider simply editing `numpy`'s source directly.

Comment: If this `$HOME/.config/ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` that you mention is a Python file that iPython simply executes at startup, you may want to consider just putting `import numpy` and then `numpy.core.arrayprint._line_width = 160` in it.

Comment: how can I access `numpy.core.arrayprint._line_width`, when I import `numpy` on start using `from numpy import  *`?  The variable `numpy.core.arrayprint._line_width` does not exist.

Comment: You can't, since `core` isn't included in `numpy`'s `__all__`. You need to `import numpy` by name, but that doesn't stop you from also doing `from numpy import *`.

Comment: The variable `_line_width` seems to be nonexistent (`np.__version__ == '1.15.1'`). It's now `_format_options["linewidth"]` (with 75 as default)

Comment: To be more precise on @Daniel comment, `np.core.arrayprint._format_options["linewidth"] = 250` or whatever you like.

Answer (score 38):

You can see your current line width with

```
numpy.get_printoptions()['linewidth']
```

and set it with

```
numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=160)
```

## Automatically set printing width

If you'd like the terminal width to be set automatically, you can have Python execute a startup script.  So create a file `~/.python_startup.py` or whatever you want to call it, with this inside it:

```
# Set the printing width to the current terminal width for NumPy.
#
# Note: if you change the terminal's width after starting Python,
#       it will not update the printing width.
from os import getenv
terminal_width = getenv('COLUMNS')
try:
    terminal_width = int(terminal_width)
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    print('Sorry, I was unable to read your COLUMNS environment variable')
    terminal_width = None

if terminal_width is not None and terminal_width > 0:
    from numpy import set_printoptions
    set_printoptions(linewidth = terminal_width)

del terminal_width
```

and to have Python execute this every time, open your `~/.bashrc` file, and add

```
# Instruct Python to execute a start up script
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.python_startup.py
# Ensure that the startup script will be able to access COLUMNS
export COLUMNS
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. While the answer provided by @Dolda2000 works, this method is cleaner and simpler. The extra info on setting up a Python startup script is also useful.

Answer (score 9):

To automatically resize both numpy and IPython whenever your window size changes, add the following to your `ipython_config.py`:

```
import IPython
import signal
import shutil
import sys
try:
    import numpy as np
except ImportError:
    pass

c = get_config()

def update_terminal_width(*ignored):
    """Resize the IPython and numpy printing width to match the terminal."""
    w, h = shutil.get_terminal_size()

    config = IPython.get_ipython().config
    config.PlainTextFormatter.max_width = w - 1
    shell = IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.instance()
    shell.init_display_formatter()

    if 'numpy' in sys.modules:
        import numpy as np
        np.set_printoptions(linewidth=w - 5)

# We need to configure IPython here differently because get_ipython() does not
# yet exist.
w, h = shutil.get_terminal_size()
c.PlainTextFormatter.max_width = w - 1
if 'numpy' in sys.modules:
    import numpy as np
    np.set_printoptions(linewidth=w - 5)

signal.signal(signal.SIGWINCH, update_terminal_width)
```

If you want to delay loading numpy until necessary, look at [Post import hooks in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40623889/303425) for a solution.

If you're not using IPython, put the above in your PYTHONSTARTUP file and remove the IPython-specific lines.

Comment: What is the object `c`?

Comment: @wim thanks for pointing that out. Fixed (it is `get_config()`).

Comment: This is nice but seems to work only with Python 3.3 or later. Earlier versions don't seem to have shutil.get_terminal_size()

Answer (score 0):

use this method :

```
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=300)
```

and widen your iphyton view using this:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:95% !important; }</style>"))
```